# Getting segmentation fault with memcpy

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, memcpy

I am having some trouble with `malloc`, arrays of pointers, and `memcpy`. I have a string called hex_string which always has a length divisible by 8. I am trying to split this string into substrings, each with 8 characters. This works fine when I have 16 characters in the string, but if I increase this to 24 characters and beyond, I get a segmentation fault. Could anyone help me out as the the reason why? I know I am using a lot of for loops that essentially run the same loop, I will condense these but I wanted to do each part of the program separately to start with.

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {

    const char * hex_string = "1c0111001f010100abcdef12";
    /* Using this value for hex_string fails - but if the 
    string is replaced with "1c0111001f010100" the program runs fine. */

    int string_length = strlen(hex_string);

    /* get the number of 8 character substrings needed 
    (using ceil to allow me to expand this to arbitrary length strings in the future) */
    int num_of_blocks = (int)ceil((double)string_length / 8); 

    /* allocate memory for pointers to each substring */
    char ** hex_array = (char **) malloc(num_of_blocks * sizeof(char));

    /* allocate 9 bytes for each substring 
    to allow for the 8 characters and the null-terminator. */
    for (int i = 0; i  < num_of_blocks; i++)
        hex_array[i] = (char *) malloc(9);

    /* split the strings into 8-character substrings and add a null-terminator */
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_blocks; i++) {
            memcpy(hex_array[i], hex_string+(i*8), 8);
            (hex_array[i])[8] = '\0';
    }

    /* print each substring */
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_blocks; i++)
        printf("substring %d = %s\n",i,hex_array[i]);

    /* free the memory allocated for each substring */
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_blocks; i++)
        free(hex_array[i]);
    /* free the memory allocated for the pointers to the substrings */
    free(hex_array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the variable `num_of_32s` defined anywhere.  Is this some sort of global which is not shown in your code?

Comment: If this is not null-termination issues, I'll go without beer for a week.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to change num_of_32s to num_of_blocks when copying the code, but forgot to change the last few. I thought it'd make it easier to understand! In my program they are 8 characters of hex, so 32-bit values.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` --> `sizeof(char*)` Sorry @Martin, no beer for you.

Comment: Standard comment - what did you find out when you ran this under your debugger?

Comment: @user3386109 - OK, but I have two bottles of Vodka ready:)

Comment: LOL, that's not fair :)

Comment: @user3386109 - Thanks, can't believe I didn't spot that. All working fine now. :)

Comment: Using the pattern `p = malloc(N * sizeof *p);` helps to avoid this problem , visually you just need to check for the `*` straight after the sizeof, instead of having to match it back to a cast several characters to the left

Comment: Rather than `int num_of_blocks = (int)ceil((double)string_length / 8);`, you can use `int num_of_blocks = (string_length + 7) / 8;` to avoid floating point..

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends and `void *` in general. C is not C++.

Comment: Kudos to you, Andrew.  Despite having a bug, your code is well written, organized, and explained.  It's easy to follow, and exceptional for a StackOverflow post.

Comment: @donjuedo Not being negative here, but can't agree with `exceptional for a StackOverflow post.` part, rather, it should say, the _expected form of posting a question_. :)

Comment: Umm.. it has magic numbers - '8' and '9'

Comment: this line: 'memcpy(hex_array[i], hex_string+(i*8), 8);' will fail on the last sub string when the original string is not an exact multiple of 8 because it will access characters beyond the end of the original string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is using the  wrong type in memory allocation - a common error.

```
// char ** hex_array = (char **) malloc(num_of_blocks * sizeof(char));
char ** hex_array = (char **) malloc(num_of_blocks * sizeof(char *));
```

With strong agreement with [@Matt McNabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb), recommend using the following.  No need for a cast.  Easier to code.  Easier to maintain.   And in this case, less likely to get the wrong type.

```
pointer_variable = malloc(n * sizeof *pointer_variable);

char ** hex_array = malloc(num_of_blocks * sizeof *hex_array);
```